# Converting a matrix into pivot form having unique values

Tags: python

I have a matrix

| User | Item | Sold |
| --- | --- | --- |
| U1 | I1 | 3 |
| U1 | I2 | 4 |
| U3 | I1 | 5 |
| U2 | I3 | 6 |

Now I want to convert it to

|  | I1 | I2 | I3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| U1 | 3 | NA | NA |
| U2 | NA | 4 | NA |
| U3 | 5 | NA | 6 |

[MATRIX](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iNY4O.png)

I tried this but it did not give me expected result

```
data = np.array(([["U1","I1",3],["U1","I2",4],["U3","I1",5],["U2","I3",6]])) 
 
rows, row_pos = np.unique(data[:, 0], return_inverse=True) 
cols, col_pos = np.unique(data[:, 1], return_inverse=True) 
 
pivot_table = np.zeros((len(rows), len(cols)), dtype=data.dtype) 
pivot_table[row_pos, col_pos] = data[:, 2]
```

Comment: What's the logic behind the transformation: doesn't make sense to me without further information?

Comment: @Navneet: To clarify, most people would expect the input row "U1, I2, 4" to be converted into a "4" in row U1 column I2 of the output, but you have the 4 in row *U2* column I2. So maybe your code is right, and you just had a mixup with the input or the expected output?

Comment: @tom yes I think the problem is with expected output only. I think there is mix up there. Btw thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try below, I have used pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {
    'User': ['U1', 'U1', 'U3', 'U2'],
    'Item': ['I1', 'I2', 'I1', 'I3'],
    'Sold': [3, 4, 5, 6]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

matrix = df.pivot(index='User', columns='Item', values='Sold')
matrix = matrix.reset_index()
matrix.columns.name = None
matrix = matrix.fillna('NA')

print(matrix)
```

Comment: Thanks for this but it is still giving me the same answer.

Comment: I think there is some mixup in expected output.